# LinkedIn Groups and Google Maps integration

Tags: google-maps, linkedin-api, mashup

Has anyone seen an implementation of Google Maps using LinkedIn group information?

Specifically I would like to plot the location of members within a group as pins on a Google Map.

Any help or guidance would be great.

Comment: This is a very good idea and question

Answer (score 4):

According to the [LinkedIn Developer API](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1002), a request to a users profile will return:

```
<person>
  ...
  <location>
    <name>
    <country>
      <code>
    </country>
  </location>
  ...
</person>
```

Which you should then be able to [Geocode](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) into the Lat/Long points.

It all really depends on whether you can get a list of people in a group. Apparently there's [not much support](http://developer.linkedin.com/message/2350#2350) for groups API yet.

Comment: @Blair: Good answer regarding the LinkedIn API. Note however that reverse geocoding is when you have lat/lon and you get returned an address. The opposite (address to lat/lon) is required, which is normal geocoding.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to get the location of your LinkedIn group members, you can geocode their addresses with the [Google Maps HTTP Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) as follows:

Simple CSV:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Oxford+Street,+London&output=csv&sensor=false
```

More Complex XML:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Oxford+Street,+London&output=xml&sensor=false
```

Simply change the "q" parameter with the address.

You will receive the Latitude and Longitude of each address through geocoding. Then it is simply a matter of putting the markers on the map in the browser through JavaScript:

```
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(GEOCODED_LAT, GEOCODED_LON)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a Qlikview (personal edition is free) implementation of the LinkedIn API's, see more on this blog:  http://www.qvsource.com/wiki/LinkedIn-Connector.ashx#Demo_Application_3